# jQuery UI not working on FireFox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery Ui is working in Safari & Chrome but doesn't work at all in FireFox.

The code is too large to paste here so I have it located at the following URL...

http://opencalendars.com/alpha/v0.9/index.php *(link has become broken over time & is no longer how it would have appeared when this question was asked.)*

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: In my FF browser it acts as if no CSS or Javascript is being used. As well as a friends browser.

Comment: what is this ocde supposed to do $(function() {
$('.').animate({ backgroundColor: "#89b7da" }, "slow");
});

Comment: On my local server there is content within the jQuery UI Tabs. It just animates something on load. Removing it doesn't effect the no CSS or JS problem.

Comment: @PhilipK - Please see my answers edit, I was able to duplicate and have it work locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js see http://jsfiddle.net/BsG6q/7/ for error in FFX.. change it to 1.6.2 and see.

the source of the problem looks like this line of code:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: $.getUrlVar('p'), cache: true, spinner: 'Retrieving data...',fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } }
).find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({ axis: "x" });;
```

> $.getUrlVar('p') is undefined!!

saw a bunch of js errors on your  site in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'
(anonymous function)scripts.js:27
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery-latest.min.js:16
f.e.extend.readyjquery-latest.min.js:16
f.c.addEventListener.B
```

and also this

```
GET http://opencalendars.com/alpha/v0.9/ajax/cal.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Have updated the live version with version 1.6.2 and removed the 'selected: $.getUrlVar('p'),' code. 
Didn't seem to help. The GET error occurs live but not on local server.

Comment: the js error doesnt occur on your local m/c and it doesnt load on ffx?  can u remve the datepicker just in case

Comment: Got it I updated version 1.6.2 and linked to the same UI that JSfiddle linked to.

Answer (score 1):

This is working here

http://jsfiddle.net/BsG6q/4/

Comment: What is this? A version you have edited? Not familiar with that site.

Comment: ah first you should be familiar with this site http://jsfiddle.net/ ;) nop i did't edited anything just copy the source from firefox and pasted there and it start working.... just try adding files 1 by one and you will catch the issue..otherwise its working with the files i added including style and ui styles with your js..

Comment: It is I've been trying to update it based on the jsfiddle.net/BsG6q/4 code, but I havn't had any lucky yet. It's getting kind of messy because there quire a few php inserts.

Comment: is it work without php inserts ? what kind of insert these are ? and where it is added...bottom line is your code is working just relax and first remove the php code and see is it working as standalone ( script and html ) than add php inserts...

Comment: I copied the JS, CSS, and HTMl exactly and not working. It must have something to do with how the framework is set up on JSfiddle vs. http://code.jquery.com/ versions.

So current version on my local server is no PHP and still not working so must be framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem using Fire Fox and the URL.

I saved the file locally in Chrome and looked at it in Fire Fox and it was fine.

I edit the local file to point to your web server and it broke.

Clearly the problem is how your server is serving the css files.  Maybe they are not using UTF-8 -- maybe they are compressing and don't have the right headers?  Something is wrong with how they server the files that Fire Fox can't handle.

Best bet to debug -- fiddler 2.  Look at the content and the headers and see if it looks different form CSS files that work.

Sadly I don't have time to do that myself right now.

---

Original Ideas:

Try adding `type="text/css"` to the link statement and using a fully qualified path.

Also add a DOCTYPE element.

Comment: Added type & DOCTYPE. no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at you HTML? The DOCTYPE should be at the top...

```
<div class="dialog" title="Message"> 
    <p>Email PWilson@OpenCalendars.com for details</p> 
</div>    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

That's not valid HTML...

Remove the div before the DOCTYPE, and Firefox should display it properly too, I'd guess...

:)

Comment: I have seen that but only happens when you click on the link labeled 'Advertise'.
When your on the page http://opencalendars.com/alpha/v0.9/index.php 
It doesn't appear appove the DOCTYPE. And still doesn't work in FireFox.

Comment: I have removed the Message div and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try fixing these errors. If it STILL doesn't work, don't hesitate to call back... :) http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fopencalendars.com%2Falpha%2Fv0.9%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I dnt think any of those errors should cos the probs that you are seeing

Comment: Maybe not. However, try firing up the error console in Firefox. It doesn't like your CSS at all. And the CSS it not valid, so why should it? http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fopencalendars.com%2Falpha%2Fv0.9%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css

Comment: shouldn't email address be obfuscated?